# Logging proxy_pass timeouts or other failures in nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a proxy setup like so:

```
    location / {
        ...
        proxy_read_timeout                  300s;
        proxy_send_timeout                  300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout               75s;

        proxy_pass                          https://$destination;
        ...
    }
```

but occasionally see requests that fail without making it to the proxied upstream. As far as I can tell, the only status detail I can find is the `$status` variable, but I'd like to know *what* failed with some more detail. Is there a way to get more information about the nature of the failure when it isn't an explicit 500 generated from the upstream?

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: I can check the error log as a one-off but I'd like to be able to put more information into the query log, as we have tooling integrated into it to parse and give quick all-up dashboard status.

Comment: You should already be ingesting the error logs, then! Get that set up.

Comment: It's a good point but doesn't answer the question at hand, alas.